# TextSpan not displaying return text flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm working on flutter app in which I used TextSpan widget for displaying the text. But when I returend the text from method TextSpan not display this text.

```
RichText(
 text: TextSpan( 
   children: [
         TextSpan(text:formatDate(comments[index].createdAt) +
          " at " formatTime(comments[index].createdAt),
           )
         ]
     )
 )


String formatDate(String time) {
var parsedDate = DateTime.parse(time);

final f = new DateFormat('MMM dd, yyyy').format(parsedDate);
String format = f.toString();
return format;
// f.format(new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(values[index]["start_time"]*1000));
}

String formatTime(String time) {
var parsedDate = DateTime.parse(time);

final f = new DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(parsedDate);
String format = f.toString();
return format;
// f.format(new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(values[index]["start_time"]*1000));
}
```

createdAt: "2019-09-30T02:55:46.428Z"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your case.

Instead of:

```
TextSpan(text:formatDate(comments[index].createdAt) +
          " at " formatTime(comments[index].createdAt),
           )
```

It should be:

```
TextSpan(text:formatDate(comments[index].createdAt) +
          " at " + formatTime(comments[index].createdAt),
           )
```

Also, I don't know what `comments[index].createdAt` represents, so I tried to directly pass hardcoded test `date` and `time` in `formatDate` and `formatTime` method calls respectively and provide `color` property in `TextSpan` which helped to display the text on screen properly. Updated sample working code below:

```
body: Center(
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                  children: [
              TextSpan(text:formatDate("2019-09-30") +
                  " at " + formatTime("2019-09-30"), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ]
                  ),
              ),
            ),
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I was forgot to give the style: color

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 RichText(
     text: TextSpan( 
       children: [
          TextSpan(text: '${formatDate(DateTime.now().toString())} at ${formatDate(DateTime.now().toString())}')   
        ]
     ),
 ),

//Replace DateTime.now() with your data
```